# How to add text to a empty files in NOTEPAD++

Tags: file, text, notepad++, addition

I have a bunch of empty files (with different names).
How can I add text to them e.g. not copy-paste the text to the 2000 files one by one.

Is this possible in NOTEPAD++?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it the same text you want to add to every file? and will the files be in the same directory?

Comment: The files are in the same directory and the text I want is the same for each file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming the text you want to add is simple enough and they are all txt files, navigate to the directory where they are and create a run.bat file with the following contents

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do (        
      echo your text here >>%%f
)
```

thanks should be given to https://stackoverflow.com/users/37923/mark and https://stackoverflow.com/users/2666/jim-buck

Naturally, I would recommend a test first before going through your thousand files.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The text I'm trying to add is formatted so I used your script to add a 1 to each file and then I replaced the 1 with the formatted text in NOTEPAD++.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a string of characters to many files you can use `echo A string of characters > *.txt` . All the text file will now contain `A string of characters`.
If the text content is in a file `text` then you can use `type text > *.txt`. Now all the *.txt file will have same content as content of file `text`. All these commands should be typed at command prompt. You must be knowing `>`,`>>`,`<`,`<<` are the redirection operators.

Answer (score 0):

A pure Notepad++ solution would use the **Find in files** variation of search, which has a **Replace in files** facility. Set **Find what** to be `\A\z` meaning start of buffer immediately followed by end of buffer; make sure that **Regular expressions** are selected. Put the required text into the **Replace with** field. Use the **Filters** and **Directory** fields and the three tick boxes (below the close button) to select the files.

**Caution** All empty files that are found by the file search criteria will be changed.