# How do I modify this BAT code to work for all subfolders?

Tags: batch-file, markdown, obsidian

I need to apply a tag to all .md files in a directory (for use in Obsidian), including all .md files in subfolders. Building off the code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993155/how-to-add-text-to-a-empty-files-in-notepad#:%7E:text=for%20%25%25f%20in%20(*.txt)%20do%20(%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20echo%20your%20text%20here%20%3E%3E%25%25f%0A)), I was able to get it to work for .md files in the same folder as the BAT file with this code:

```
for %%f in (*.md) do (        
      echo #unpolished >>%%f
)
```

If someone could modify it to apply to all subfolders, I would be grateful.

Though ideally, if it's not too difficult, could the code be adjusted to do these two things:

1. Write to the *beginning* of the .md file.
2. Instead of the #unpolished tag, could it add this code:

```
---
tags: unpolished
aliases:
cssclass:
---
```

The second part is not as significant if too difficult, and it's not timely if someone could add it later. I've tried various batch commands, VBA code, and Notebook++ but I have limited experience and have been unable to get it to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not a code request service. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key to quickly learn how including the subdirectories can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your feedback. [Redditor](https://www.reddit.com/r/CodingHelp/comments/12lzsuy/help_with_batch_file/) was able to provide a succinct code solution.

This code worked for me:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "folder=your file path here"
for /r "%folder%" %%f in (*.md) do (
  (echo ---& echo tags: unpolished& echo aliases:& echo cssclass:& echo ---& echo. & type "%%f") > "%%~dpnf.tmp"
  move /y "%%~dpnf.tmp" "%%f" > nul
)
```

**WARNING** - for other users, create a backup of your directory before testing.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is to establish a filename-lister

```
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /s /a-d filemask') do (
)
```

This executes the `dir` command, ignoring directorynames (`/a-d`) for files matching the filemask (`*.md` in your case), scanning subdirectories (`/s`) and listing in basic form (`/b`) that is, without headers, footers or details - names only. A list is built in memory of all of the files in the tree and then each filename found is assigned to `%%b` in turn.

The `delims=` turns off the default `for /f` processing into tokens (see `for /?` from the prompt for documentation - or hundreds of SO responses) so the entire filename is assigned to `%%b`

```
I prefer to avoid ADFNPSTXZ (in either case) as metavariables (loop-control variables) 
ADFNPSTXZ are also metavariable-modifiers which can lead to difficult-to-find bugs 
(See `for/f` from the prompt for documentation)
```

Since `%%b` contains the full absolute path to the file, it may contain spaces or other confounding characters, so best to `"quote the filename"` when used. which overcomes most problems.

Next step would be to create a temporary file containing your required prefix data as trying to insert at the start of a file is dicey.

```
echo --->tempfile.###
echo tags: unpolished>>tempfile.###
echo aliases:>>tempfile.###
echo cssclass:>>tempfile.###
echo --->>tempfile.###
```

would do that - note that there is only *ONE* `>` in the first of those lines. This starts a new file, so if there's an existing `tempfile.###`, it will be overwritten. The `>>` appends to the file.

BUT

That's highly inefficient as each `echo` statement opens, writes and closes the file.

```
(
 echo ---
 echo tags: unpolished
 echo aliases:
 echo cssclass:
 echo ---
)>tempfile.###
```

opens, writes and closes just once - and is easier to read and maintain as well. Note that the `echo`es are contained between parentheses `(…)`.

Then append your selected file in `%%b` to the tempfile

```
type "%%b">>tempfile.###
```

so the tempfile then contains the preamble data and the original file,

and then replace the original using `move` tempfile original.

```
move tempfile.### "%%b"
```

Since this is a batch file, the `/y` switch to bypass confirmation of overwriting a file is not required, but there's no harm in including it.

```
move /y tempfile.### "%%b"
```

this will generate messages which can be suppressed by appending `>nul` and/or `2>nul` to the `move` command line. `>nul` suppresses normal messages (`1 file(s) moved`) and `2>nul` suppresses error messages.

And there you have it. Within the filename-lister, create the preamble in the tempfile, append the original to the tempfile and move the resultant tempfile over the original.

obligatory warning: **Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Useful extension:

If you run this process more than once, each file will acquire another copy of the preamble.

```
findstr /x /c:"tags: unpolished" "%%b" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
 rem did not fine "tags: unpolished" as a line in the file, so insert it
 ...
) else (echo skipping "%%b" - already processed)
```

will attempt to find a line in the file `%%b` which exactly (`/x`) matches the constant string (`/c:string`) and set `errorlevel` to `0` if FOUND, hence don't process or non-0 if not found, hence process.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of a perl script that will update all `.md` files in a given directory and its sub directories:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use Object::Pad;
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    die "Bad arguments. Please give start directory name" if @ARGV != 1;
    my $start_directory = shift @ARGV;
    my $self = Main->new(dir => $start_directory);
    $self->update_all_md_files_with_tag();

}

class Main;
field $_dir :param;
use feature qw(say);
use File::Find;

method update_all_md_files_with_tag() {
    find(sub {$self->wanted($_)}, $_dir);
    say "Done.";
}

method wanted($fn) {
    return if !(-f $fn);
    return if $fn !~ /\.md\z/;
    $self->add_tag($fn);
}

method read_file($fn) {
    open (my $fh, "<", $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    my $str = do {local $/; <$fh>};
    close $fh;
    return $str;
}

method add_tag( $fn ) {
    my $content = $self->read_file($fn);
    $self->update_file_content_with_frontmatter(\$content);
    ## TODO: remember to take backup of all files before running this script!!
    $self->write_file( $fn, \$content );
    say ".. $fn";
}

method write_file( $fn, $content ) {
    open (my $fh, ">", $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    print $fh $$content;
    close $fh;
}

method get_frontmatter_template {
    return <<"END";
---
tags: unpolished
aliases:
cssclass:
---
END
}

method update_file_content_with_frontmatter($content) {
    my $frontmatter = $self->get_frontmatter_template();
    $$content = $frontmatter . $$content;
}
```